# Spivak, A Twice Differentiable Function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality

I am currently working on Spivak. I am in need of help or a hint on this question, because every which way I try this question whether it be with Cauchy MVT or just plain MVT, I get to some promising point and end up coming back out with nothing. I've been trying at this problem since last Friday.

The problem:

> Prove that if $f$ is a twice differentiable function with $f(0)=0$ and
>   $f(1)=1$ and $f'(0) = f'(1) = 0$, then $|f''(x)|\geq4$ for some $x \in (0, 1).$
>   In more picturesque terms: A particle which travels a unit distance in
>   a unit time, and starts and ends with velocity $0$, has at some time an
>   acceleration $>4$. Hint: Prove that either $f''(x)\geq4$ for some $x\in(0,1)$,
>   or else $f''(x)\leq4$ for some $x\in(0,1)$.

I really don't know how else to approach this. I've tried arbitrary intervals say $(0,x)$, intervals of $(0,1/2)$ and $(1/2,1)$ via Cauchy MVT and 'regular' MVT, I've tried his "hint", I've tried breaking it into cases where $f'(1/2)<1$, $f'(1/2)>1$ and $f'(1/2)=1$ with no real luck.

I'm sure there's something I'm not seeing that I should be seeing, but I figure after a week I should probably ask around, say, not at school. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If $\bigl(\forall x\in[0,1]\bigr):\bigl\lvert f''(x)\bigr\rvert<4$, then there a $x_0\in\left[0,\frac12\right]$ such that\begin{align}f\left(\frac12\right)&=f(0)+\frac12f'(0)+\left(\frac12\right)^2\frac{f''(x_0)}2\\&=\left(\frac12\right)^2\frac{f''(x_0)}2\\&=\frac{f''(x_0)}8\\&<\frac48\\&=\frac12\end{align}and there is a $x_1\in\left[\frac12,1\right]$ such that\begin{align}f\left(\frac12\right)&=f(1)+\left(\frac12-1\right)f'(1)+\left(\frac12-1\right)^2\frac{f''(x_1)}2\\&= 1+\frac{f''(x_1)}8\\&>1-\frac48\\&=\frac12.\end{align}

Comment: Hi Jose! Thank you. Are you using Taylor's remainder theorem here? Is there any way to express this only using Cauchy MVT &/or MVT? I believe that this theorem isn't introduced for another 200 or so pages in Spivak. Very slick though.

Comment: You apply the MVT to $f'$: if $f''(x)<4$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, then$$\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}x<4$$and therefore $f'(x)<4x$. So, again by MVT$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x<4x$$and so $f(x)<4x^2$. In particular, $f\left(\frac12\right)<\frac12$.

Comment: Right, so that's where I was at originally, but how are you getting $f(1/2)<1/2$? I don't see how it follow that if $f(x)<4x^2$ then $f(1/2)<1/2$? The lowest bound I see for $f(1/2)$ if $f(x)<4x^2$ is $f(1/2)<4\cdot(1/2)^2=1$.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't follow from what I wrote. My mistake. But then I went to see the [answer book](http://www.enthusiasticallyconfused.com/Mathematics/Spivak%27s%20Calculus/Michael%20Spivak%20Answer%20Book%20for%20Calculus%203rd%20Edition%20%201994.pdf) and… it has the same answer (with more details)! Perhaps that Spivak made an error here.

Comment: Indeed, I'm still not sure how to proceed with the question. I enjoy the Taylor method, but I figure since only MVT has been introduced I suspect you should be able to prove it with only those tools introduced thusfar.